# php inside <a> of HTML

Tags: php, html

I am a beginner and trying to use PHP statement inside `<a>` tag of HTML. I don't know whether it is possible or not and I tried to search it on Google, but I couldn't find any answer. Below is the code I am trying to execute.

Whenever I run this code, I do not get any error but the my browser does not display the value of $link1, $link2 and $link3 which I put inside the `<a>` tag of HTML.

I saved the document as index.php

```
<?php
$title = 'Shellitic';
$link1 = 'Home';
$link2 = 'Contact';
$link3 = 'About';
?>
<head>
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Welcome to <?php echo $title; ?> </h1>
<p></br></p>
<p>To visit our home page, click on the <a href="#"> <?php $link1; ?> </a> button</p>
<p>To visit our contact page, click on the <a href="#"> <?php $link2; ?> </a> button</p>
<p>To visit our About page, click on the <a href="#"> <?php $link3; ?> </a> button</p>
</body>
```

Comment: you should write like below :<?php echo $link1; ?>

Answer (score 2):

You need to echo the values:-

```
<?php echo $link1; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Some servers may accept this

```
<?= $link1; ?>
```

But it is typically safer to use

```
<?php echo $link1; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add echo command.
Like this:

```
<?php echo $link1; ?>
```